# Is Attribute Routing possible in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, attributerouting

I am trying to enforce a route parameter to be `guid` but getting below error

> "Exception while executing function: GetUser -> One or more errors
>   occurred. -> Exception binding parameter 'req' -> Invalid cast from
>   'System.String' to 'System.Guid'."

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Admin, "get", Route = "GetUser/{userId:guid}")] HttpRequestMessage req,
            Guid userId, ILogger log)
        {
        }
```

The request i am making is `http://localhost:7071/api/GetUser/246fb962-604d-4699-9443-fa3fa840e9eb/`

Am i missing some thing? Cannot we enforce route parameter to be guid ?

Answer (score 6):

> Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Guid'

I can reproduce same issue when use Route constraint `{userId:guid}` in Azure httptrigger function on my side, you can try to [open an issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues) to give a feedback.

Besides, if possible, you can try to call [Guid.TryParse method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert the string back to Guid value in function code, the following code is for your reference.

```
public static string Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "GetUser/{userId:guid}")]HttpRequestMessage req, string userId, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    Guid newGuid;

    var resmes = "";

    if (Guid.TryParse(userId, out newGuid))
    {
        resmes = "userid: " + newGuid;
    }
    else {
        resmes = "error";
    }

    return resmes;
}
```